# Many classes and xml files doesn't appear in work space , pls help me Android

Tags: android

I completed in developing my apps " Event Database " , which took me many months , as I am a newbie

I had my workspace location in " F:\Users\Desktop " and after few updates of my code I used to copy the project and save it to another location

While developing the project, I use to save the drawables like xml , images etc through eclipse (i.e; I used to copy drawables and save by right click on " drawable folder " in eclipse and paste it)

And I created many classes and xml files as per rules in Android Development (i.e: right click on package -> new -> classes) and xml file as per same rules

When I completed my project after very hard work , I was signing my project to publish it to GOOGLE PLAY , suddenly my eclipse restarted and it showed RED mark in my project . I checked and was shocked , My project was deleted from eclipse but NOT from " F:\Users\Desktop "

Then I tried to import that project to eclipse , it showed an some error . I had a doubt , then checked the folder in " F:\Users\Desktop " , I found that " Many Classes, Drawable including xml files , images in NOT presented in work space which is the updated project folder

Please somebody help me to get My hard work a worth , I don't know what to do and it is impossible for me to once again do all those work which I have done since many many months

Comment: Try This : http://aglazkov.wordpress.com/2010/07/18/one-way-to-restore-eclipse-workspace/

Comment: And in future make habit of taking backup of your project to other location. Keep in mind this one also : http://mcuoneclipse.com/2013/04/03/restore-deleted-files-in-eclipse-with-local-history/

Comment: I have backup Sir , but I too contains the same problem , pls look my comment below to @Android Priya

Comment: @YuDroid - This not worked ....

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you delete your project by mistake from its path but as it was present in eclipse so it creates the same folder at its path but without class and xml files. check your trash or try recreate from history in eclipse.

Comment: I didn't deleted . The actual thing is while I was adding resources to the project , it was reflecting only to eclipse and NOT to work space ... however how to do the steps a you said ?

Comment: right click on your project in eclipse and click on restore from local history.

Comment: Than sorry dude u can't get back your changes. have u check in your trash?

Comment: how to go for Trash ??

Comment: Trash means recycle bin